# Using multiprocessing with pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to separate my input loop from my game logic in my simple snake game that I've made with pygame, but, I'm really struggling to figure out why nothing is happening when I run the program.

I've tried importing pygame in the subprocess, I checked for errors on the subprocess, and got nowhere. I looked on google, but I wasn't able to find any usable examples, or similar issues. Has anybody ever figured any of this stuff out?

Okay, here's the code:

```py
import pygame
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import random as rnd

pygame.init()


def event_to_dict(event: pygame.event) -> dict:
    return {
        'type': event.type,
        'key': event.key if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN else None,
    }


class SnakeBoard:
    def __init__(self, rows: int, columns: int):
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.vertices = []
        self.odd_column = False

        self.buff = []
        for _ in range(self.rows):
            self.buff.append([' ' for _ in range(self.columns)])

    def initialize(self):
        for r in range(self.rows):
            for c in range(self.columns):
                self.buff[r][c] = ' '
        self.odd_column = (self.columns >> 1) % 2 == 1
        self.buff[self.rows >> 1][self.columns >> 1] = '\u25cb'
        self.vertices = [(self.rows >> 1, self.columns >> 1)]

    def place_food(self):
        while True:
            r = rnd.randint(0, self.rows - 1)
            c = rnd.randint(0, self.columns - 1)
            codd = c % 2 == 1
            if (codd and self.odd_column or not codd and not self.odd_column) and self.buff[r][c] != '\u25cb':
                self.buff[r][c] = '\u25c9'
                break

    def tick(self, direction: int) -> bool:
        nr, nc = self.vertices[-1]

        if direction == 0:
            nr -= 1
        elif direction == 1:
            nc += 1
        elif direction == 2:
            nr += 1
        elif direction == 3:
            nc -= 1
        else:
            print("Invalid direction for snake")
            exit(1)

        if nr >= self.rows or nc >= self.columns or nr < 0 or nc < 0 or self.buff[nr][nc] == '\u25cb':
            return False

        self.vertices.append((nr, nc))
        self.vertices.pop(0)
        return True


class SnakeGame(SnakeBoard):
    def __init__(self, rows: int, columns: int):
        super().__init__(rows, columns)
        self.score = 0
        self.direction = 0
        self.initialize()
        self.place_food()

    def tick(self, direction: int = -1) -> bool:
        v = super().tick(self.direction if direction < 0 else direction)

        if self.buff[self.vertices[-1][0]][self.vertices[-1][1]] == '\u25c9':
            self.score += 1
            self.vertices.append(self.vertices[-1])
            self.place_food()

        for r in range(self.rows):
            for c in range(self.columns):
                if (r, c) in self.vertices:
                    self.buff[r][c] = '\u25cb'
                elif self.buff[r][c] != '\u25c9' and self.buff[r][c] != ' ':
                    self.buff[r][c] = ' '
        return v


class GameLoop(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, q: object, size: list):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = q
        self.size = size

        self.g = SnakeGame(size[1] // 10, size[0] // 10)
        self.g.initialize()
        self.g.place_food()

        self.screen = None
        self.game_surf = None
        self.font = None

    def run(self) -> None:
        try:
            import pygame
            pygame.init()

            self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)
            self.game_surf = pygame.Surface(self.size)
            self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('roboto', 16)

            is_running = True
            while is_running:
                if self.q.poll(0):
                    d = self.q.recv()
                    if d is not None:
                        if d['type'] == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                            if d['key'] == pygame.K_a:
                                self.g.direction = 3
                            elif d['key'] == pygame.K_s:
                                self.g.direction = 2
                            elif d['key'] == pygame.K_d:
                                self.g.direction = 1
                            elif d['key'] == pygame.K_w:
                                self.g.direction = 0
                            elif d['key'] == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                                is_running = False
                    else:
                        is_running = False

                self.game_surf.fill((255, 255, 255))

                for ri, r in enumerate(self.g.buff):
                    for ci, c in enumerate(r):
                        if c == '\u25cb':
                            # print("Drawing a snake at {}, {}".format(ri * 10, ci * 10))
                            pygame.draw.circle(self.game_surf,
                                               (0, 0, 255),
                                               ((ci * 10) + 5, (ri * 10) + 5),
                                               5)
                        elif c == '\u25c9':
                            # wprint("Placing food at {}, {}".format(ci, ri))
                            pygame.draw.circle(self.game_surf,
                                               (0, 127, 255),
                                               ((ci * 10) + 5, (ri * 10) + 5),
                                               5)

                timg = self.font.render("Score: {}, Level: {}".format(self.g.score, self.g.score // 10 + 1),
                                        True,
                                        (0, 0, 0))

                self.screen.blit(self.game_surf, (0, 0))
                self.screen.blit(timg, (0, 0))
                pygame.display.flip()

                if self.g.tick():
                    time.sleep(1 / ((int(self.g.score / 10 + 1)) * 10))
                else:
                    timg = self.font.render("Game Over! Would you like to try again?", True, (0, 0, 0))
                    self.screen.blit(timg, ((self.size[0] >> 1) - 150, self.size[1] >> 1))
                    timg = self.font.render("Yes", True, (0, 0, 0))
                    btn_pos = ((self.size[0] >> 1) - 25, (self.size[1] >> 1) + 20)
                    self.screen.blit(timg, btn_pos)
                    pygame.display.flip()

                    while True:
                        event = pygame.event.wait()
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            is_running = False
                            break
                        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                            mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                            if btn_pos[0] - 5 <= mx <= btn_pos[0] + 30 and btn_pos[1] - 5 <= my <= btn_pos[1] + 20:
                                self.g.initialize()
                                self.g.place_food()
                                self.g.score = 0
                                break
            self.q.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = [800, 600]

    parent, child = mp.Pipe()
    p = GameLoop(child, size)
    p.start()

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False

            ed = event_to_dict(event)
            parent.send(ed)

    parent.close()
    p.join()
    pygame.quit()
```

Sorry, it's kinda strange, this was migrated from the console to pygame, so some of the logic is still using the unicode symbols.

Comment: If you want to get events in pygame, you need to have a window. Your main process does not have a window, so it will not get any events by calling `pygame.event.get()`. Your window runs on another process, so you need to capture the events on that process. I don't understand why you're using the `multiprocessing` at all.

Comment: I'm using multiprocessing because the single processed version was missing keystrokes

Comment: You don't need multiprocessing for this simple task of Snake.

Comment: @eligolf then what do you propose?

Comment: Just detect key presses the normal way to change direction of the snake. I am just saying, multiprocessing is really complicated, not worth it when it is not needed :)

Comment: @eligolf, I already did that, and pygame seems to miss keypresses when they're really close together, so I'm trying to find a way to speed up the reading process, hence multiprocessing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally in GUI applications it's common to want to separate the GUI from the logic.
There are benefits to doing this as it means your GUI remains responsive even if your logic
is busy. However, in order to run things concurrently there are many drawbacks, including
overheads. It's also important to know that python is not 'thread safe', so you can break
things (see race conditions) if you're not careful.

### Simplified example with no concurrency

Your example is quite complex so lets start with a simple example: A simple pygame setup with
a moving dot

```py
import pygame
import numpy as np

# Initialise parameters
#######################
size = np.array([800, 600])
position = size / 2
direction = np.array([0, 1])  # [x, y] vector
speed = 2
running = True

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.update()

# Game loop
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                direction = np.array([0, -1])
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                direction = np.array([-1, 0])
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                direction = np.array([0, 1])
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                direction = np.array([1, 0])

    position += direction * speed

    if position[0] < 0 or position[0] > size[0] or position[1] < 0 or position[1] > size[1]:
        running = False

    pygame.time.wait(10)  # Limit the speed of the loop

    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (0, 0, 255), position, 10)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

We're going to split off the game logic from the gui

### Mutliprocessing and other options:

So multiprocessing in python allows you to utilise multiple cores at the same time, through multiple interpreters.
While this sounds good, as far as I/O goes: it comes with higher overheads and doesn't help at all (it will likely
hurt your performance). Threading and asyncio both run on a single core i.e. they aren't 'parrallel' computing. But
what they allow is to complete code while waiting for other code to finish. In other words you can input commands
while your logic is running happily elsewhere.

**TLDR**: as a general rule:

- CPU Bound (100% of the core) program: use multiprocessing,
- I/O bound program: use threading or asyncio

### Threaded version

```py
import pygame
import numpy as np
import threading
import time

class Logic:
    # This will run in another thread
    def __init__(self, size, speed=2):
        # Private fields -> Only to be edited locally
        self._size = size
        self._direction = np.array([0, 1])  # [x, y] vector, underscored because we want this to be private
        self._speed = speed

        # Threaded fields -> Those accessible from other threads
        self.position = np.array(size) / 2
        self.input_list = []  # A list of commands to queue up for execution

        # A lock ensures that nothing else can edit the variable while we're changing it
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def _loop(self):
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Wait a bit to let things load
        # We're just going to kill this thread with the main one so it's fine to just loop forever
        while True:
            # Check for commands
            time.sleep(0.01)  # Limit the logic loop running to every 10ms

            if len(self.input_list) > 0:

                with self.lock:  # The lock is released when we're done
                    # If there is a command we pop it off the list
                    key = self.input_list.pop(0).key

                if key == pygame.K_w:
                    self._direction = np.array([0, -1])
                elif key == pygame.K_a:
                    self._direction = np.array([-1, 0])
                elif key == pygame.K_s:
                    self._direction = np.array([0, 1])
                elif key == pygame.K_d:
                    self._direction = np.array([1, 0])

            with self.lock:  # Again we call the lock because we're editing
                self.position += self._direction * self._speed

            if self.position[0] < 0 \
                    or self.position[0] > self._size[0] \
                    or self.position[1] < 0 \
                    or self.position[1] > self._size[1]:
                break  # Stop updating

    def start_loop(self):
        # We spawn a new thread using our _loop method, the loop has no additional arguments,
        # We call daemon=True so that the thread dies when main dies
        threading.Thread(target=self._loop,
                         args=(),
                         daemon=True).start()


class Game:
    # This will run in the main thread and read data from the Logic
    def __init__(self, size, speed=2):
        self.size = size
        pygame.init()
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
        self.logic = Logic(np.array(size), speed)
        self.running = True

    def start(self):
        pygame.display.update()
        self.logic.start_loop()

        # any calls made to the other thread should be read only
        while self.running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    # Here we call the lock because we're updating the input list
                    with self.logic.lock:
                        self.logic.input_list.append(event)

            # Another lock call to access the position
            with self.logic.lock:
                self.window.fill((0, 0, 0))
                pygame.draw.circle(self.window, (0, 0, 255), self.logic.position, 10)
                pygame.display.update()

        pygame.time.wait(10)
        pygame.quit()
        quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game([800, 600])
    game.start()
```

### So what was achieved?

Something light like this doesn't really need any performance upgrades. What this does allow though, is that
the pygame GUI will remain reactive, even if the logic behind it hangs. To see this in action we can put the logic
loop to sleep and see that we can still move the GUI around, click stuff, input commands etc.
change:

```py
# Change this under _loop(self) [line 21]
time.sleep(0.01)

# to this
time.sleep(2)

# if we tried this in the original loop the program becomes glitchy
```